# Labeling a Summed grouping row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've been tasked with fixing a query which currently creates totaling row with GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP.

```
SELECT  CONVERT(date, ShipDate),
        DelNum,
        SUM(ShipQty),
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN ShipDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ShipDate END ASC,CASE WHEN DelNum IS NULL THEN 'Z' ELSE DelNum END ASC) 
FROM Shipments 
WHERE Company = 'ABC' AND CustNum = 3 
GROUP BY ShipDate, DelNum, ShipQty WITH ROLLUP
```

This was the query I was given. I've been adding some labeling and some ordering to make it more readable:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(date, ShipDate),
        CASE WHEN (GROUPING(DelNum) = 1) THEN 'SUB TOTAL FOR ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, ShipDate, 111)
            WHEN (GROUPING(ShipQty) = 1) THEN 'SUB TOTAL FOR ' + DelNum
            --WHEN (GROUPING(Total) = 1) THEN 'TOTAL'
            ELSE ISNULL(DelNum, 'UNKNOWN')
        END AS DelNum,
        SUM(ShipQty) Total,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN ShipDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ShipDate END ASC,CASE WHEN DelNum IS NULL THEN 'Z' ELSE DelNum END ASC) 
FROM Shipments 
WHERE Company = 'ABC' AND CustNum = 3 
GROUP BY ShipDate, DelNum, ShipQty WITH ROLLUP 
ORDER BY ShipDate, DelNum, Total ASC
```

What I'm having a problem with is the row I commented out. How can I label the total row. I keep getting `Total` as unrecognized.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Total` is a column alias, and you can't reference it in the `GROUPING` function.  You also can't put the aggregate in the `GROUPING` function like this:

```
WHEN (GROUPING(SUM(ShipQty)) = 1)
```

What you *can* do is check that all the group fields have `GROUPING() = 1`:

```
CASE WHEN (GROUPING(ShipDate) = 1 and GROUPING(DelNum) = 1 and GROUPING(ShipQty) = 1) THEN 'TOTAL'
            WHEN (GROUPING(DelNum) = 1) THEN 'SUB TOTAL FOR ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, ShipDate, 111)
            WHEN (GROUPING(ShipQty) = 1) THEN 'SUB TOTAL FOR ' + DelNum           
            ELSE ISNULL(DelNum, 'UNKNOWN')
        END AS DelNum
```

Note that you need to move that check to the top of the `CASE` or else the `CASE` will short circuit before it gets evaluated (since each individual `GROUPING` equals 1 by themselves).